# Unity: how to register class for more common type?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following problem:

I have some classes and interfaces in the first assembly:

```
public interface IA {}
public interface IB : IA {}
internal class C : IB {}
```

and class C is registered in the Unity container in this assembly.

```
Container.RegisterType<IB, C>();
```

and now I want to register something like

```
Container.RegisterType<IA, C>();
```

in the another assembly, but class C is not accessible. And

```
Container.RegisterType<IA, IB>();
```

does not work, because IB is interface. 
How can I link base interface IA with already registered IB?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply cannot use internal type inside another library but you can resolver **IB** so:

```
Container.RegisterType<IA>(new InjectionFactory(x=>x.Resolve<IB>()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are basically trying to use an implemtation that is marked as internal, from another assembly, which won't work.  You need to take away the internal qualification if you want to use it elsewhere.